# a natural question on standard example of nowhere differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

An example of a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which one usually visits is the following with some variations on the constants $2$ and $10$:

$$f(x)=\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{\cos{(10^k\pi x)}}{2^k}.$$

My question is then following; it is about the function "$\cos$" used to define $f$, and its possible variations. (I don't know technical details of this fact; i.e. I don't have gone through complete proof of this fact that $f$ is nowhere differentiable).

Suppose $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a *non-constant* function satisfying following conditions.

(1) $g$ is bounded.

(2) $g$ is periodic.

(3)  $g$ is a differentiable  (one may assume this to be infinitely differentiable if needed in following question.)

Then define 
$$F(x)=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{g(10^k x)}{2^k}.$$

Is it true that $F$ is nowhere differentiable?

Comment: A constant function $g$ would seem to be a counterexample, right?

Comment: Conditions (2) and (3) imply (1).

Comment: @Aaron: Sorry, I forgot to mention this condition.

Comment: I think so, if $g$ has period $1$.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if you could do this with a function that was $0$ on just a neighborhood of $x=0$? I think this could be done in a periodic, non-constant, infinitely differentiable way, but maybe it would still be differentiable at $x=0$ (or other places). I'm not prepared to prove or even really assert this to be the case; just thinking out loud.